# How to prevent a change of a specific flag from triggering a rebuild?

Tags: scons

I've added the option `-fdiagnostics-color` for GCC in my build.
It only changes colors in error commands so I don't want the targets to rebuild when this option is the only thing that has changed.

For example with this `SConstruct`:

```py
env = Environment()
if 'color' in ARGUMENTS:
    env.Append(CPPFLAGS=f'-fdiagnostics-color={ARGUMENTS["color"]}')
env.Program('main.cc')
```

Calling `scons color=never` and then `scons color=always` will cause the target file to be built 2 times.

Can I somehow tell SCons to not rebuild the target if only this option has changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SCons indeed has a pair of markers `$(` and `$)`.

Everything that you'll put between them will be ignored while evaluating if a target needs to be rebuilt.
(It works only if the string with the markers is passed to the function `subst` but this happens to almost every string, including ones passed to `Action`s, `Command`s and construction variables.)

```py
env = Environment()
if 'color' in ARGUMENTS:
    env.Append(CPPFLAGS=f'$( -fdiagnostics-color={ARGUMENTS["color"]} $)')
env.Program('main.cc')
```

Comment: This is correct. To amplify a little, SCons rebuilds a target if dependencies change, or if the action changes. The action signature (hash) is recomputed to check the latter; anything between `$(` and `$)` is excluded for the signature calculation only - still used when the command is issued.